# How do I extend Ordered Dictionary in Python to include insert after key

Tags: python, oop

I want to make a dictionary that is ordered and that can have the order manipulated.

I was looking in the documentation and it appeared to be a doubly linked list. Looking at the definition of OrderedDict in VSC provided something of the sort with an example of how it implements move to end:

```
class OrderedDict(dict):

    ...

    def move_to_end(self, key, last=True):
        '''Move an existing element to the end (or beginning if last is false).

        Raise KeyError if the element does not exist.
        '''
        link = self.__map[key]
        link_prev = link.prev
        link_next = link.next
        soft_link = link_next.prev
        link_prev.next = link_next
        link_next.prev = link_prev
        root = self.__root
        if last:
            last = root.prev
            link.prev = last
            link.next = root
            root.prev = soft_link
            last.next = link
        else:
            first = root.next
            link.prev = root
            link.next = first
            first.prev = soft_link
            root.next = link
```

I want to implement a version that has an insert after key function

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class indexedDict(OrderedDict):

    def insertAfter(self, oldKey, newKey):
        link = self.__map[newKey]
        link_prev = link.prev
        link_next = link.next
        soft_link = link_next.prev
        link_prev.next = link_next
        link_next.prev = link_prev
        
        dest = self.__map[oldKey]
        dest_next = dest.next
        link.next = dest_next
        link.prev = dest
        dest_next.prev = soft_link
        dest.next = link
```

I keep running into errors about

`AttributeError: 'indexedDict' object has no attribute '__map'`

I have read that code mangling occurs with the `__prefix` during extending so I have tried replacing

```
dest = self.__map[oldKey]
```

to

```
dest = self._OrderedDict__map[oldKey]
```

still

`AttributeError: 'indexedDict' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__map'`

Where is my error with implementing the extension to `OrderedDict`?

Comment: "Looking at the Definition of OrderedDict in VSC" almost certainly not the actual definition, which I'm pretty sure is implemented in C.

Comment: Beside the point, but that first error doesn't match that code. The missing attribute should be `_IndexedDict__map`, not `__map`. Maybe you wrote `insertAfter` as a separate function and patched it onto the class or something?

Comment: Also, off-topic, but class names should be *UpperCamelCase*, so `IndexedDict`. And for extending a Python class, I'd use the Python convention on method names, *snake_case*, so `insert_after`.

Comment: @juanpa Yup, there's a C implementation in CPython. I found it here: [`Objects/odictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/odictobject.c). IDK how it gets into `_collections`, but that's where it's imported [here in `collections`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/90de4b76b9ef557710419fcc0d11ce90b18ac05c/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L333).

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga & wjandrea I had my suspicions
@wjandrea 1 I am not sure what you mean with this I had written this as a separate class, class IndexedDict  in its entirety and I wanted to get access to the __map from the implementation of OrderedDict so I could modify that structure
2 Thanks for informing me on standards, I am self taught mostly and that is an area that I am lacking 

I also tried "super.__map" and "super._OrderedDict__map"  to no avail, which if ordereddict is compiled C would make plenty of sense
2